# Mozilla like Dynamic bookmarks in Safari browser

Tags: macbook-pro, ios, safari, mobile-safari, bookmarks

I was using Mozilla previously and Mozilla has a very good bookmark feature, also known as dynamic bookmark. It would allow me to pass a variable to a bookmarked URL and the variable's value will be inserted into the URL. I don't want to "Edit  Address" of the bookmark every time, like in this photo 
[image]

It would stay as the variable.

Refer to this link to understand the feature: https://www.ghacks.net/2015/06/22/how-to-use-dynamic-bookmarks-in-firefox/

**How can the same thing  be achieved in Safari?** This feature is very helpful for bugzilla, jira and lot of other developer tools where I would directly input the uniqueid of the entry to land directly on that page instead of searching it from the main page.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8H2U.png you mean this?

Comment: no... I do not want to edit address everytime.